If a contract does not explicitly implement ERC-2771 can Meta-transaction work with it?
Here's the gist. I have an account that got hacked but that compromised account is the owner of a contract I deployed some time ago. I want to gain access to the tokens in my contract but if I send gas to this compromised address to do a transaction, it gets drained so I am trying to use Meta-Transaction to pay for the gas on behalf of the account with another account.
I have come up with a fowarder contract but what happens is, when I try to call the approve method on the target contract(my token contract) it gets called as if the forwarder contract was the caller of the approve method instead of the compromised address.
The target contract, in this case, does not explicitly implement ERC-2771. Could that be the reason why this is not working? Is there something I am not doing right or i there a better alternative to this?
Here's my Forwarder contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MetaTransaction {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // This struct defines the meta-transaction
    struct MetaTx {
        address from;
        address to;
        uint256 value;
        bytes data;
        uint256 nonce;
        uint256 gasPrice;
        uint256 gasLimit;
    }

    // A mapping to store nonces for each address
    mapping(address => uint256) public nonces;

    // Function to execute meta-transactions
    function executeMetaTransaction(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 nonce,
        uint256 gasPrice,
        uint256 gasLimit,
        bytes memory signature
    ) public {
        require(nonce == nonces[from], "Invalid nonce");
        nonces[from]++;

        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(from, to, value, data, nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit));
        require(recoverSigner(hash, signature) == from, "Invalid signature");

        (bool success, ) = to.call{gas: gasLimit}(abi.encodePacked(data, from));
        require(success, "MetaTransaction failed");
    }

    // Function to recover the signer of a hash
    function recoverSigner(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) public pure returns (address) {
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;
        // Check the signature length
        if (signature.length != 65) {
            return address(0);
        }
        // Divide the signature in r, s and v variables
        assembly {
            r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
            s := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 0x60)))
        }
        // Version of signature should be 27 or 28, but 0 and 1 are also possible versions
        if (v < 27) {
            v += 27;
        }
        // If the version is correct return the signer address
        if (v != 27 && v != 28) {
            return address(0);
        } else {
            return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
        }
    }
}

here's how I call the forwarder:
const BSC_TESTNET_RPC_URL = "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/";

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(BSC_TESTNET_RPC_URL);

const reclaimerPrivateKey = "";
const sponsorPrivateKey = "";

const sponsorSigner = new Wallet(sponsorPrivateKey, provider);
const userSigner = new Wallet(reclaimerPrivateKey, provider);

const userAddress = ''
const tokenReceiver = '';

const targetContractAddress = 'target_ADDRESS';
const metaTXAddress = 'TX_ADDRESS';


const mockContract = new Contract(targetContractAddress, erc20ABI, userSigner)
const metaTransactionContract = new Contract(metaTXAddress, metaTXABI, sponsorSigner)

const myCall = async () => {
    const metaTx = {
        from: userAddress,
        to: targetContractAddress,
        value: parseEther('0'),
        data: mockContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('approve', [tokenReceiver, parseEther('50')]),
        nonce: await metaTransactionContract.nonces(userAddress),
        gasPrice: parseUnits('10', 'gwei'),
        gasLimit: 510000
    };
    
    // Hash the meta-transaction
    const hash = keccak256(solidityPacked(
    ['address', 'address', 'uint256', 'bytes', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'],
    [metaTx.from, metaTx.to, metaTx.value, metaTx.data, metaTx.nonce, metaTx.gasPrice, metaTx.gasLimit]
));

    // Sign the hash
    const signature = await userSigner.signMessage(getBytes(hash));
    
    const tx = await metaTransactionContract.executeMetaTransaction(
        metaTx.from,
        metaTx.to,
        metaTx.value,
        metaTx.data,
        metaTx.nonce,
        metaTx.gasPrice,
        metaTx.gasLimit,
        signature,
        {
            gasPrice: parseUnits('10', 'gwei'),
            gasLimit: 200000
        }
    );

    console.log("Calling tx:::::");
    const txResp = await tx.wait();
    console.log("TX called:: ", txResp);
}


myCall();


Yeah if the target contract doesn't integrate ERC2771 you can't spoof the msg.sender.

I want to gain access to the tokens in my contract but if I send gas to this compromised address to do a transaction, it gets drained

If this is the problem, the easiest solution is using a bundle of private transactions. See the guide https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-mev-share/searchers/sending-bundles
Basically you can send two transactions at the same time:

fund some gas to your hacked wallet
use the hacked wallet to transfer the tokens or whatever


I'll give this a try.
